# How to connect to remote OpenVas scanner with python?

Tags: python, linux, security, ssh, openvas

I am exploring OpenVas tool for a project requirement, openVas is currently managed by Greenbone. I am getting error when I try to use remote scanner using python api.

I did all initial configuration, setup the required gui account etc and was able to scan the required systems manually however when I try to do the same using Python Api its not working. There isn't any example available on internet nor in there manual to verify my code.
I have used [https://pypi.org/project/python-gvm/] api.

I wrote simple code but its not working..

```
from gvm.connections import SSHConnection
from gvm.protocols.latest import Gmp
from gvm.transforms import EtreeTransform
from gvm.xml import pretty_print

connection = SSHConnection(hostname='192.168.1.84',username='alex',password='alex@123')
gmp = Gmp(connection)
gmp.authenticate('admin', 'admin')

# Retrieve current GMP version
version = gmp.get_version()

# Prints the XML in beautiful form
pretty_print(version)
```

I am getting error-

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/punshi/PycharmProjects/nessus_api/openvas-greenbone.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:39: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
  m.add_string(self.Q_C.public_numbers().encode_point())
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:96: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for unsafe construction of public numbers from encoded data will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point
  self.curve, Q_S_bytes
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:111: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
  hm.add_string(self.Q_C.public_numbers().encode_point())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/punshi/PycharmProjects/nessus_api/openvas-greenbone.py", line 8, in <module>
    gmp.authenticate('admin', 'admin')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gvm/protocols/gmpv7.py", line 211, in authenticate
    response = self._read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gvm/protocols/base.py", line 54, in _read
    return self._connection.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gvm/connections.py", line 126, in read
    raise GvmError('Remote closed the connection')
gvm.errors.GvmError: Remote closed the connection

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tested SSH connection manually so the problem is either with my code or some other.

Additional Detail-

```
Ubuntu 16,
Greenbone Security Assistant 7.0.3 (gui)
Open Vas - 9.0.3
```

Answer (score 6):

I've exactly the same problem that I solved it with `TLSConnection` instead of `SSHConnection`. Here is your code:

```py
import gvm
from gvm.protocols.latest import Gmp
from gvm.transforms import EtreeTransform
from gvm.xml import pretty_print

connection =gvm.connections.TLSConnection(hostname='192.168.1.84')
gmp = Gmp(connection)
gmp.authenticate('admin', 'admin')

# Retrieve current GMP version
version = gmp.get_version()

# Prints the XML in beautiful form
pretty_print(version)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am exploring OpenVas tool for a project requirement, openVas is currently managed by Greenbone.

Just a side note. OpenVAS is developed by Greenbone since many years now. Therefore we did rename the project to **Greenbone Vulnerability Management (GVM)** with version 10. Only the actual scanner component will be still named after OpenVAS. See https://community.greenbone.net/t/is-openvas-manager-and-gvmd-the-same/1777/3 for more details.

Using the SSHConnection needs some additional setup at the remote server. Using TLSConnection might be easier but needs also changes in the settings of gvmd/openvasmd because it is only listening on a unix socket by default.

Comment: Define `some additional setup at the remote server` :-)